# Custom membership and role provider in MVC 3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0, membership-provider

I have custom membership and role provider (C#) in my .net 4 (webform based) web application.

I am moving my web app to MVC 3.

How do I migrate or implement my custom providers in MVC 3?

Any tutorial or pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can migrate them quite easily. A default MVC application makes the same Membership provider calls. Just load the project they are compiled in (or import that class files if you dont want the whole project) and point your web.config at them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to make any changes to your providers